# Как получить случайную lat long вокруг моего места

Tags: php, google-maps

Как получить случайную lat long  вокруг моего места чтобы *не вышел из границы*

Comment: Где входные данные? Что в итоге вы хотите получить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$earthRadius = 6371000;
$myLat=...;
$myLng=...;
$maxRadius=...;
$angle=2 * M_PI * mt_rand(0, 1000) / 1000;
$radius=mt_rand(0, $maxRadius);

$north = sin($angle) * distance;
$east = cos($angle) * distance;
$newLat = $myLat + ($north / $earthRadius) * 180 / M_PI;
$newLon = $myLng + ($east / ($earthRadius * cos($newLat * M_PI / 180))) * 180 / M_PI;
```